# How does lambda multiplication works?

Tags: lambda, multiplication, reduce

[A Tutorial Introduction to the Lambda Calculus](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf)

This article introduces the multiplication function

> The multiplication of two numbers x and y can be computed using the following
>   function:
>
> (λxyz.x(yz))
>
> The product of 2 by 2 is then:
>
> (λxyz.x(yz))22
>
> which reduces to
>
> (λz.2(2z))
>
> The reader can verify that by further reducing this expression, we can obtain the expected result 4.

I have no idea how  can  (λz.2(2z))  reduce to 4. Can anyone show me the process?

the 2 in lambda function is λsz.s(s(z)), and the 4 is λsz.s(s(s(s(z)))).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain formally the result by applying the substitution, like in the previous examples of the note that you have cited.

Since:

```
2 ≡ λsz.s(s(z))
```

we first substitute the second instance of it in `(λz.2(2z))` (changing the variable names to avoid capture of free variables):

```
 (λz.2((λxy.x(x(y)))z))
```

which becomes equal to (substituting `x` with `z`):

```
(λz.2(λy.z(z(y))))
```

then we apply again the definition of 2 (with a new renaming of the variables):

```
(λz.((λwu.w(w(u)))(λy.z(z(y))))))
```

which becomes equal to (substituting `w` with `λy.z(z(y))`):

```
(λz.(λu.(((λy.z(z(y)))((λy.z(z(y)))u)))))
```

now we can repeat the substitution in the rigthmost lambda, substituting `y` with `u`:

```
(λz.(λu.((λy.z(z(y)))(z(z(u))))))
```

and finally we can apply the last substitution, replacing `y` with `z(z(u)`:

```
(λz.(λu.z(z(z(z(u))))))
```

which is 4.

As final remark, note that one could be convinced by the correctness of the definition by considering that a number *n* is a function with two arguments that applies the first argument *n* times to the second one. So, `(λz.2(2z))`, is the function that applies two times the function `2z`, which is the function that applies two times z, so that the result is the function that applies four times `z` to its argument.